# Can I back up my app's SQLite database to iCloud?

Tags: ios, icloud

I'd like to have a 'backup' and 'restore' button in my app that just copies the entire SQLite database as a blob to iCloud. The database will always be small as it contains only hand-entered information.

Is this possible using iCloud or do I need to create an external service to manage this?

(If it matters: my app is created using the NimbleKit framework and jQuery Mobile UI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer: it is possible.

[iCloud + Storage of media in iPhone Documents folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762743/icloud-storage-of-media-in-iphone-documents-folder) & [Will iCloud sync the files in Document folder of all apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752513/will-icloud-sync-the-files-in-document-folder-of-all-apps)

Comment: storing a whole sqlite db is nothing apple will like though

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand this, I will probably serialize backups to the Documents folder as xml or JSON or whatever so I can keep multiple backups, rather than storing the whole database. Do you think Apple would look on that more favourably?

Comment: I think they would, yes :)

Comment: Storing the SQLite there for backup purposes should be no problem-- Apple doesn't care if the format is SQLite or JSON or XML.

Comment: No, thats true but they care very much about filesize! And they rejected apps for that so one should not write ONE monolithic database - thats my point